# Pandas : how to get the unique number of values in cells when cells contain lists?

Tags: python, pandas

For some mysterious reason I have a dataframe that looks like

```
index             col_weird      col_normal
2012-01-01 14:30  ['A','B']      2
2012-01-01 14:32  ['A','C','D']  4
2012-01-01 14:36  ['C','D']      2
2012-01-01 14:39  ['E','B']      4
2012-01-01 14:40  ['G','H']      2
```

I would like to resample my dataframe every 5 minutes, and

- get the unique number of elements across all the lists in `col_weird`,
- get the mean of `col_normal`

Of course, using `resample().col_weird.nunique()` would fail for the first task because I want the unique number of elements: that is, between `14:30` and `14:35` I expect this number to be 4, corresponding to A,B,C,D.

Over the same period, the mean of `col_normal` is of course 3.

Any idea how to get that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can expand `list` to `Series` first:

```
df = df['col'].apply(pd.Series).stack().reset_index(drop=True, level=1)
print (df)
2012-01-01 14:30    A
2012-01-01 14:30    B
2012-01-01 14:32    A
2012-01-01 14:32    C
2012-01-01 14:32    D
2012-01-01 14:36    C
2012-01-01 14:36    D
2012-01-01 14:39    E
2012-01-01 14:39    B
2012-01-01 14:40    G
2012-01-01 14:40    H
dtype: object
```

Then use `resample`:

```
df = df.resample('1H').nunique()
print (df)
2012-01-01 14:00:00    7
Freq: H, dtype: int64
```

Comment: very smart but what if the original dataframe contains other columns than `col`?

Comment: I think you can then set index with all columns and then apply `pd.Series`

Answer (score 1):

Group by `pd.TimeGrouper('5Min')` then apply an obnoxious function.

```
df.groupby(pd.TimeGrouper('5Min')).col.apply(lambda x: x.apply(pd.Series).stack().unique().shape[0])

index
2012-01-01 14:30:00    4
2012-01-01 14:35:00    4
2012-01-01 14:40:00    2
Freq: 5T, Name: col, dtype: int64
```

Comment: thanks buddy but your output does not seem to be correct?

Comment: @ noobie fixed my post

Comment: thanks again but I have to credit jezrael for the answer. he gave the same solution before you. sorry bud

Comment: @Noobie np jezrael rocks