# Pandas: how to get the unique values of a column that contains a list of values?

Tags: python, pandas

Consider the following dataframe

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'name' : [['one two','three four'], ['one'],[], [],['one two'],['three']],
                   'col' : ['A','B','A','B','A','B']})       
df.sort_values(by='col',inplace=True)

df
Out[62]: 
  col                   name
0   A  [one two, three four]
2   A                     []
4   A              [one two]
1   B                  [one]
3   B                     []
5   B                [three]
```

I would like to get a column that keeps track of all the unique strings included in `name` for each combination of `col`.

That is, the expected output is

```
df
Out[62]: 
  col                   name    unique_list
0   A  [one two, three four]    [one two, three four]
2   A                     []    [one two, three four]
4   A              [one two]    [one two, three four]
1   B                  [one]    [one, three]
3   B                     []    [one, three]
5   B                [three]    [one, three]
```

Indeed, say for group A, you can see that the unique set of strings included in `[one two, three four]`, `[]` and  `[one two]` is  `[one two]`

I can obtain the corresponding number of unique values using [Pandas : how to get the unique number of values in cells when cells contain lists?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38355931/pandas-how-to-get-the-unique-number-of-values-in-cells-when-cells-contain-list) :

```
df['count_unique']=df.groupby('col')['name'].transform(lambda x: list(pd.Series(x.apply(pd.Series).stack().reset_index(drop=True, level=1).nunique())))


df
Out[65]: 
  col                   name count_unique
0   A  [one two, three four]            2
2   A                     []            2
4   A              [one two]            2
1   B                  [one]            2
3   B                     []            2
5   B                [three]            2
```

but replacing `nunique` with `unique` above fails.

Any ideas?
Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the solution

```
df['unique_list'] = df.col.map(df.groupby('col')['name'].sum().apply(np.unique))
    df
```

[image]

Comment: interesting. `sum` with strings?!

Comment: @Noobie it's worse than that. It's sun on list of lists. It produces a concatenated list over which I apply np.unique

Comment: hehehe. i just tried but it seems your nice solutions fails when there are missing values for col. In that case I get `TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "int") to list`. Replacing the missing values with `fillna('')` or `fillna('[]')` does not work. Any ideas?

Comment: @Noobie if you want a unique master list per group defined by `'col'`, do you expect missing values in `'col'` to be considered it's own group?

Comment: @Noobie just `df = df.dropna(subset=['col']).copy()` ahead of time

Comment: yes but I dont want to lose obvervations in `df`. Does`df.col.map(df.dropna(subset=['col']).groupby('col')['name'].sum().apply(np.unique))` make sense?

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
uniq_df = df.groupby('col')['name'].apply(lambda x: list(set(reduce(lambda y,z: y+z,x)))).reset_index()
uniq_df.columns = ['col','uniq_list']
pd.merge(df,uniq_df, on='col', how='left')
```

Desired output:

```
  col                   name              uniq_list
0   A  [one two, three four]  [one two, three four]
1   A                     []  [one two, three four]
2   A              [one two]  [one two, three four]
3   B                  [one]           [three, one]
4   B                     []           [three, one]
5   B                [three]           [three, one]
```